# How to copy with SCP between two servers using key auth?

Tags: ssh, scp

I can log in via SSH using key authentication to SERVER1 and SERVER2. However, I can't copy files between the two servers. Why? How can I copy between them? (the data that I have to copy is bigger than my notebooks HDD)

My notebook runs Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and the two servers are AIX 5300-10-02-0943. My `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on my notebook contains the public keys for these two servers. I use `tsocks` because I have to use an SSH tunnel to reach these two servers. The two servers can ping each other.

```
[USER@NOTEBOOK ~] tsocks scp -v -i /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa -p -r root@SERVER1:/PATH/TO/DIR root@SERVER2:/PATH/TO/DIR
Executing: /usr/bin/ssh '-v' '-x' '-oClearAllForwardings yes' '-n' '-l' 'root' 'SERVER1' 'scp -v -r -p' '/PATH/TO/DIR' 'root@SERVER2:/PATH/TO/DIR'
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to SERVER1 [SERVER1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.2p1+sas
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.2p1+sas pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'SERVER1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts:59
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 151
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -p /PATH/TO/DIR root@SERVER2:/PATH/TO/DIR
Executing: program /applications/ssh/5.20.15.0/bin/ssh host SERVER2, user root, command scp -v -r -p -t /PATH/TO/DIR
OpenSSH_5.2p1+sas, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to SERVER2 [SERVER2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.2p1+sas
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.2p1+sas pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 1984, received 3848 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6903.4, received 13389.2
debug1: Exit status 1


[USER@NOTEBOOK ~] tsocks scp -i /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa -p -r root@SERVER1:/PATH/TO/DIR root@SERVER2:/PATH/TO/DIR
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
[USER@NOTEBOOK ~]
```

Comment: does /dev/tty exist? try this: http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Can't_open_/dev/tty:_No_such_device_or_address_Error_(Linux)

Answer (score 13):

This is very easy to fix. See, the source server does not know the destination server and it can't ask you to confirm the identity, since you don't have a terminal open there:

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

So just log in to the source account/server and try to ssh (or scp) to the dest account, accept the host key and cancel login/scp. You should be able to copy.

```
local $ ssh source@src-server
src-server $ ssh dest@dst-server
The authenticity of host 'destination (10.0.0.x)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 71:ec:c0:86:7f:b6:51:eb:76:c8:1f:2f:ba:0a:f4:20.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
dest@dst-server's password: ^C
src-server $ exit

local $ scp -r source@src-server:/path/to/files dest@dst-server:/path/to/files
```

If not, try:

```
local $ scp -r -o "ForwardAgent=yes" source@src-server:/path/to/files dest@dst-server:/path/to/files
```

If you have a SSH key with access to the destination server and the source server does not, adding `-o "ForwardAgent=yes"` will allow you to forward your SSH agent to the source server so that it can use your SSH key to connect to the destination server.

Answer (score 6):

A little diagnosis: from this

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -p /PATH/TO/DIR root@SERVER2:/PATH/TO/DIR
[...]
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

I'd suspect (guess) it works this way, the server-to-server copy with `scp` logs into `SERVER1` and executes the `scp` command to send the file to `SERVER2`; thus the caller (from `SERVER1`) has to authenticate itself.  Now this fails since it's non-interactive (there's no `/dev/tty`) and there's no way to ask for a passphrase.

This means copying the key to `SERVER1` (I can't tell if this is possible in your situation) could probably fix the issue (I think...)  (*If there is no passphrase...which is rather bad*)

**Edit** A solution could be the following, use `sshfs` to access the files you want to send, send them via `scp` from the `sshfs`-mounted directory.  This should get you the needed interactivity (if the guess above was right) and keep all keys local.

Comment: sshfs is not an option.

Comment: So the problem is that SERVER1 can't ssh to SERVER2 with key auth? Are there any ssh client parameters for this to use the key on my notebook?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid.  You could, however, use `ssh SERVER1 scp *args-YOU-specifiy*` for a little more flexibility.  Maybe some `stdin` trickery could help... I'm not sure.

Comment: @utopiabound's answer (using `ssh-agent`) sounds a lot better than `stdin` trickery.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried this and it works for me between two systems, a few differences:

- I have an SSH agent running with my SSH key added (`ssh-add`)
- I have ssh-agent forwarding enabled by default

Try the following:

```
ssh-add
scp -v -o "ForwardAgent=yes" -p -r root@SERVER1:/PATH/TO/DIR root@SERVER2:/PATH/TO/DIR
```

Comment: still "Host key verification failed."

Comment: @LanceBaynes Ensure that you've logged into SERVER2 from SERVER1 as root.  Maybe you don't have it in root's known hosts file on SERVER1?

Answer (score 3):

you might want to use the `-3` option of scp, it directs the traffic through your notebook.

i.e. `[USER@NOTEBOOK ~] scp -3 root@SERVER1:/PATH/TO/DIR root@SERVER2:/PATH/TO/DIR`

Answer (score 1):

Try this options for ssh:

```
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
-o UserKnownHostsFile=.ssh/known_hosts [OPTIONAL]
```

In my case, i trying to connect with ssh from inside SP in postgreSQL.
First attemp failed:

```
pc_ubuntu_db=# SELECT command('ssh -q -v admin@10.30.134.26 hostname');
debug1: Server host key: RSA 0a:28:83:72:d7:7d:89:93:96:a1:1b:e2:f9:22:85:62 
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
        Host key verification failed.
```

The source of problem: can't write in know_host

```
pc_ubuntu_db=# SELECT command('ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i admin@10.30.134.26 hostname');
debug1: Server host key: RSA 0a:28:83:72:d7:7d:89:93:96:a1:1b:e2:f9:22:85:62
Warning: Permanently added '10.30.134.26' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
...
Transferred: sent 2672, received 2040 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 214358.6, received 163657.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Next connection output:

```
debug1: Server host key: RSA 0a:28:83:72:d7:7d:89:93:96:a1:1b:e2:f9:22:85:62
debug1: Host '10.30.134.26' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
```

success !!!